# Terraform AWS IAM AssumeRole

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I've created a Terraform module with 5 Lambda functions, each one with an IAM role, policy and an assignment like this:

```
    resource "aws_lambda_function" "myFunction"{
      function_name = "myFunction"
      role          = aws_iam_role.myFunction_iam.arn
      handler       = "index.handler"
      runtime = "nodejs12.x"
      s3_bucket = "myBucket"
      s3_key = "path/to/archive.zip"
  
      environment {
        variables = {
          my_var= "my_val"
        }
      }
    }

    resource "aws_iam_role" "myFunction_iam" {
      name = "myFunction_iam"

      assume_role_policy = <<EOF
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
          },
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Sid": ""
        }
      ]
    }
    EOF
    }

    resource "aws_iam_policy" "myFunction_policy" {
      name        = "myFunction_policy"
      description = "myFunction"

      policy = <<EOF
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:${var.region}:${var.account_id}:*"
            },
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "logs:CreateLogStream",
                    "logs:PutLogEvents"
                ],
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:logs:${var.region}:${var.account_id}:log-group:/aws/lambda/${aws_lambda_function.myFunction.function_name}:*"
            ]
           },
           ...
       ]
    }
    EOF
    }

    resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "myFunction_attach" {
      role       = aws_iam_role.myFunction_iam.name
      policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.myFunction_policy.arn
    }
```

This works...but only with about 70% chance because quite often I receive this error message when calling the function:

```
Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda
```

At first, I looked for an error in a special function but after several apply/delete runs I see that it happens at random. I guess the problem is the order in which resources are created. I tried to add a depends_on attribute to myFunction waiting for myFunction_attach but then I receive an error about circular dependencies.

Any ideas how to set up the permissions in the proper order so I can trust in the created resources?

Thanks in advance!

Regards Christian

Comment: The terraform code looks good to me. No idea why this function has trouble assuming the role.

Comment: What is the rest of your `myFunction_policy`? You have only showed its part.

Comment: Do you find that it works if you see this error, wait a minute or two, and then run `terraform apply` again to retry just the `aws_lambda_function` create? If so, unfortunately I think you're seeing propagation delay within AWS itself: sometimes it can take several minutes for IAM objects to become visible to all services in all AWS regions, which can sadly lead to situations like this where Terraform is taking all of the actions in the correct order itself but the _effects_ of those actions happen in a different order within AWS itself.